# Getting class from ear/war in ear/lib/jar returns ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

My project structure is the following. Server is Glassfish 4. IDE - netbeans 7.4. Project temp is used by project a.

```
EAR
 + lib/temp.jar
 + a.war
```

`Temp.jar` contains core classes. They are used by war. `Temp.jar` doesn't import any files from war, and it must know about war nothing. But, `temp.jar` has classes that creates instances of war classes by reflection (according to xml file). Here I get `ClassNotFoundException`. How can it be fixed? Is it possible to fix or I have wrong project structure?

Note: I didn't put temp.jar in a.war as there can be different war files that can use this jar.

Comment: Is there an `application.xml` file? Does it contain a `<library-directory>` element?

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos Thank you for you time. No, there is no any application.xml

Comment: I think according to specs your setup *should* work. However could you create a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in your WAR (under the content root, i.e. side-by-side with `WEB-INF`) and place an entry as follows: `Class-Path: lib/temp.jar`

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos Result is the same. War classes can reach jar classes without problem. Jar classes can't reach war file.

Comment: My failure!!! I did not notice the exact question (use classes of *WAR* from *JAR*). Still, one **dirty** way (have never tested, be warned) is to place a similar Class-Path entry in the manifest of the *JAR*: `Class-Path: ../a.war`. But I would recomend placing the shared classes in *another JAR* and referencing that from both the WAR and the JAR.

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos Thank you. This war keeps the files which belong only to it. It will ruin all the application structure. I asked more correct question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958573/glassfish4-access-isolation-settings-for-classes-in-modules-and-libraries-for

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos I found the answer and published it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

If we put jar into ear/lib folder then the classes in it can be accessed but they can't access the classes out of lib (in this case there is no need to add something to manifest file of war).

If we put jar in root of ear or in any other folder ear/bum than the classes of these jar can access war classes.

So I conclude, that /lib is monodirectional, any other are bidirectional.

Hope it will save someone a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Add jar file to the you lib folder.
Change MANIFEST.MF and add the particular jar path to Bundle-ClassPath.

That worked for me.